# R: Replace 0s in the column by the numbers for Cohort Analysis

Tags: r, analysis

This question is extension to my earlier question (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857769/how-to-replace-column-values-for-cohort-analysis))

I got the data into this format:
[image: Before]

I would like my data to be in the following format:

[image: After]

Notice that the 0 in the first row of the Month2 column is replaced by the 9 from the second row of the Month2 column. Similarly in Month3 column the 0s are replace by the numbers from below rows

What I am looking to achieve is move the numbers in each column from lower rows to the top rows to replace the 0s

Any help is really appreciated! :)

**EDIT**
I have similar data set as above but the 0s are in a different place:

```
    x <- cbind(x1 = 10:17, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5),x3 = 21:28,x4 = 31:38, x5 = 41:48)
    x[][lower.tri(x[])] <- 0

 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
 10  4 21 31 41
  0  3 22 32 42
  0  0 23 33 43
  0  0  0 34 44
  0  0  0  0 45
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
```

I am looking for output to be as follows:

```
 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
 10  4 21 31 41
  3 22 32 42  0
 23 33 43  0  0
 34 44  0  0  0
 45  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have tried modifying the earlier code that was given by @akrun. But was unsuccessful.

Any pointers on how to go about? TIA!!!

Comment: There may be a better way, but check out this answer on [shifting columns in data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322537/2715819).  You'd have to adjust to shift up instead of down, but seems like it would work.

Comment: Let me try that. But I feel that would work if I am trying to shift all the rows by the same number. Instead, I am trying to shift it based on the column and number of 0s. Month2 column shifts 1 space up. Month3 column shifts 2 spaces up and so on...I might probably need to do a loop. Thanks for the start though!

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming you'd be looping through columns.  Looks like akrun has a better solution below, though.

Comment: Use the `rev` function for this.  No need to loop

Comment: Some really clever answers in the question linked by @RishiG, plus the one below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
  apply(dat[,-(1:2)], 2, FUN=function(x) c(x[!!x],x[!x]) )
  #     Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6
  #[1,]      9      7      6      4      0
  #[2,]      9      5      3      0      0
  #[3,]      7      6      0      0      0
  #[4,]      8      0      0      0      0
  #[5,]      0      0      0      0      0
```

To keep the `data.frame` intact it may be better to use `lapply`. In general, if the columns are of different class, using `apply` would coerce it to matrix and you will generally get a single `class`.  Here, it wouldn't matter because the columns are all numeric.  Still, I would prefer `lapply`.

```
 dat[,-(1:2)] <- lapply(dat[,-(1:2)], function(x) c(x[!!x], x[!x]))
 dat
 #   Month_Start_Date Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6
 #1       2010-01-01     10      9      7      6      4      0
 #2       2010-02-01     10      9      5      3      0      0
 #3       2010-03-01     10      7      6      0      0      0
 #4       2010-04-01     10      8      0      0      0      0
 #5       2010-05-01     10      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: @ssdecontrol I just happened to remember solution from a similar question recently

Comment: Thanks akrun!! This worked with some modifications on my actual data!

Comment: @akrun - I have an extension question to  my earlier one...any pointers on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @akrun Got it! Silly syntax error! Thanks though :)!